# Resetting new password, token became empty

Tags: php, mysql, token

I am trying to write the script for resetting password, i have got the putting the token into database, and checking if the token exist in the database, and to the part where i am going to reset the database. But for some reason,it is updating the database where there are no tokens. I am not sure why.... I am very new to coding, hope my code isnt too hard to read and have too much flaws.

```
 <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();
    include 'connect.php';


    $token = isset($_GET['token'])?$_GET['token']:"";


        echo"$token";


    $check=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM Test WHERE reset = '$token'")or die( mysqli_error($con));
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check)){

            $email = $row['email'];

             }
    if (mysqli_num_rows($check)==0)
          echo ("Token Doesnt exist");

        elseif($_POST) {






     //get form data



     $password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password1']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

     if (!$password){
        echo "Please fill out all fields"; 
     }
     else if ($password1 !== $password)
     {
         echo "Password don't match";

     }
     else 
     {
         echo"$email";
         echo"token";
        //encrypt password
        $password = md5($password);

        //check if username already taken
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Test SET password = '$password'
                    where email = '$email';") or die(mysqli_error($con));



               //register into database


    echo "Added";


           }
        }





    else
    {

    ?>

    <form action='ResetPassword.php' method='POST'>
    Your new password:<br />
    <input type='password' name='password1'><p />


    Re-enter your new password:<br />
    <input type='password' name='password'><p />

    <input type='submit' name='Change Password' value='Change Password'>
    </form>

    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: echo $token; is exist?

Comment: yer i put in the echo to see if they exist, the first time i echo it, it exists and echo the token no problem. Then second time in the else statement, the echo $email, and echo$token, they dont exist anymore, i dont know why they disappeared.

Comment: I sure hope you are not using the `md5()` hashing method for ALL of the passwords in the database. It is a broken hashing method and it is not a way of encrypting passwords.

Comment: add hidden in your form <input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?php echo $_GET['token'];?>'>

Comment: This is just the first time testing this for my own learning purpose, i will update and upgrade on those. Because at the moment, i cant even update the passwords lol

Comment: Reset tokens should be treated as passwords, so storing them in clear text isn't recommended. Also, using md5() to hash passwords is ... well, it's bad :)

Comment: I am confused, is that the reason why it doesnt update my passwords? Because the problem at the moment is its updating the passwords without tokens everytime when 1 new password is submitted. But no password with token is updated.

Comment: this is just for testing purposes to see if it updates the password, i am using $key = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
$password1  = md5($_POST['password'].$key); on the other thing, but the thing is i cant even update the password, so i will figure out the md5 part later

Comment: If i remove this line  $token = isset($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : ""; it gives an error undefined Index for the $_GET['token'] but it echos the token with no problem tho

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
    session_start();
    include 'connect.php';
    $token = isset($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : "";
    if(!empty($token)) {
        $check=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM Test WHERE reset = '$token'")or die( mysqli_error($con));
        if (mysqli_num_rows($check)> 0) {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check)
          $email = $row['email'];
        }
        else {
          echo 'Email not found with this Token';
        }
    }
    else {
      echo 'Token does not exist';
    }
    if(!empty($email) && isset($_POST['changepass'])) {
      $password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password1']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
      if (!$password){
        echo "Please fill out all fields"; 
      }
      else if ($password1 !== $password) {
         echo "Password don't match";
      }
      else {
        //encrypt password
        $password = md5($password);
        //check if username already taken
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Test SET password = '$password' where email = '$email'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        echo "Added";
     }
   }
   if(!isset($_POST['changepass'])){?>
    <form action='ResetPassword.php' method='POST'>
    Your new password:<br />
    <input type='password' name='password1'><p />
    Re-enter your new password:<br />
    <input type='password' name='password'><p />
    <input type='hidden' name='token' value='<?php if(isset($_GET['token'])) echo $_GET['token'];?>'>
    <input type='submit' name='changepass' value='Change Password'>
    </form>
    <?php }
```

Comment: Just gave it a try, it echo token does not exist even if it exist, and it displays the entry fields even if token doesnt exist.

Comment: I am not sure why, on mine, the token became empty when it is in the else statement

Comment: try echo $token; not echo"token";

Comment: It is blank if i echo $token, $token became blank, email is also blank

Comment: If i hard set the token in the update part, then it works, but in the top part the token display with no problem, then token suddenly became empty

Comment: If i remove this line  $token = isset($_GET['token']) ? $_GET['token'] : ""; it gives an error undefined Index for the $_GET['token'] but it echos the token with no problem tho